# usergrid 2.1 ql not working with old records. portal also not giving the old records, but records count is available

Tags: performance, cassandra, usergrid

usergrid 2.1 ql not working with old records. portal also not giving the old records, but records count is available,

I tried without ql and it working fine, but in my project, I am using ql. No way to remove it from the project.

If I insert the new records. Then ql is working find with new records. Is the usergrid 2.1 is not stable?

Previously I used usergrid 1.2. and I never faced any issue like db corrupt. After upgrading the usergrid I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had issues with moving a Usergrid installation to a new server.
While we were already on Usergrid 2.1, we still used Cassandra 1.2.
When we set up the new server, we wanted to go meet all the requirements and wanted to upgrade Cassandra to 2.1, too.

That's were our issue was. The Cassandra records from 1.2 are not compatible to 2.1 and must be upgraded step by step.
We had to subsequently upgrade from 1.2.19 to 2.0 and then to 2.1.

Pleas have a look at the https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/NEWS.txt.
Therein is describe the necessary upgrade steps between the versions.

## The  Culprit

We could not export the schema from Cassandra using the node tool. Some datatypes, used by Usergrid, contain very long prefixes, which break the JSON format and terminates the export.

We needed to export and reimport the schema with `cassandra-cli` instead of `nodetool`.